# Where are all mount points stored in Linux

Tags: c, linux, mount-point

I want to know where all mount points are stored; i.e. under any specific directory?

I want to be able to list all the existing mount points using a C Program. Which system call or function should I use?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5070801/monitoring-mount-point-changes-via-proc-mounts
 helpful?

Comment: /etc/mtab holds the table with mounted filesystems.

Answer (score 8):

They are located in the /proc/mounts "file", which you can read and parse.

Comment: Since it in /proc directory, looks like it is not persistent in disk. So how it get stored when power is off?

Comment: They're stored in /etc/fstab

Comment: Is /etc/fstab stored in a filesystem of partition? If yes, how does kenel find /etc/fstab during booting when no file system mounted?

Comment: Yes it is. The kernel boot configuration stores which filesystem is to be mounted at / , When the / filesystem (that has to include atleast the basic /bin/ /etc /lib/ /sbin/ and similar) is mounted , /etc/fstab can be read to mount other filesystems.

Comment: So kernel boot configuation is stored in a specifial place like MBR or something, instead of file system?

Comment: Almost. The MBR configuration does not have a lot of space, it  just stores which disk/partition the actual configuration is stored on, so the next stage of the boot loader can read that configuration.(usually stuff in the  /boot/ filesystem - which a boot loader can read before the kernel is even loaded.