# How does Nautilus mounts network shares

Tags: linux, system-calls, mount, gnome, gvfs

I need to know how does GNOME/Nautilus mounts a network shares (like smb://-shares through Nautilus), what syscalls it calls to it.

I setted up __NR_mount syscall hook in kernel, but it never calls. So, Nautilus calls something else. But what? If I try to mount my share through a 'mount -t cifs', my hook executes, but if I mount it from Nautilus, it doesn't.

My goal is kernel filtering of network shares mounting by hooking syscalls in my kernel module.

I've tried to found it in gvfs-mount and Nautilus sources, but without any result. So, where can I find some information about it or what exactly syscalls Nautilus performs to mount network shares?

Comment: Nautilus uses gvfs. [gvfsbackendsmb.c](https://github.com/GNOME/gvfs/blob/master/daemon/gvfsbackendsmb.c) uses libsmbclient. But gvfs is userspace filesystem, so it probably calls one mount on startup then all calls are redirected to it.

Comment: @KamilCuk, well, I've intercepted `fuse_mount` and `fuse_mkdir`. As Wikipedia says, gvfs implemented through a FUSE. When I make dir in terminal in smb-share - my kernel hook of `fuse_mkdir` calls successfully. But in Nautilus nothing hooks calls. So... Is there any way to filter network shares in kernel?

Comment: You may find a solution for that in this related question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5070801/